# Notification intent closes app on up/back-navigation

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-notifications, android-navigation

My App has the following activity hierarchy:

**A -> B -> C**

So far, everything works well. Now I want to add a Notification. When the user clicks on it, I want to close all child activities of A and start an instance of C, which has A as parent, without B as intermediate Activity:

**A -> C**

To achieve this I used Androids TaskStackBuilder as shown [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#SimpleNotification) to build the notification. But this results in the app being closed (without error, checked *logcat*) when the user presses the back button or uses the up-navigation in the top bar. What did I do wrong?

```
...
Intent intent = new Intent(NotificationService.this, C.class);
Intent parentIntent = new Intent(NotificationService.this, A.class);

TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(NotificationService.this);
stackBuilder.addNextIntent(parentIntent);
stackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
...
```

My AndroidManifest.xml looks like this:

```
<activity android:name=".activities.A"
          android:label="@string/app_name"
          android:launchMode="singleTask">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

<activity android:name=".activities.B"
          android:parentActivityName=".activities.A"
          android:launchMode="singleTop">
</activity>

<activity android:name=".activities.C"
          android:parentActivityName=".activities.B">
</activity>
```

Comment: Why don't you implement it with onBackPressed? It is much more easy to implement.

Comment: That is the solution I went with. But I'm not really satisfied with this solution. Android provides launchModes and the TaskStackBuilder for exactly the purpose I have and for me it looks like the most intuitive solution if it worked with the provided tools. I just can't figure out, what I did do wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I was using OxygenOS with an OnePlus One when I discovered this issue. Yesterday, there were some updates and now it works *without changing anything*.

It works with `Intent` and with `ParentStack` as *Adeel Ahmad* suggested. Maybe it was just an OS issue. Anyways, problem solved. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(NotificationService.this, C.class);

TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(NotificationService.this);
stackBuilder.addParentStack(B.class);
stackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent);
```

Try this. I Haven't tested this but `addParentStack(B.class)` should add parent declared for `B` in `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: Tried this, but it still closes the app on back/up. I assume that this solution is under the hood equivalent to passing an Intent of the parent Activity's class.

Comment: @Jeyp strange I remember using it like this in an app. Your `stackBuilder` is fine. There might be some other issue, for a start try removing `android:launchMode="singleTask` and see if that changes anything

Comment: Removing the `launchMode` does not change the behavior. I think the stack is built correctly but I have no clue why this leads to closing the app - or how I could avoid this.